# SP2007 - Where find workFlow subscription ID?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, subscriptions

I need to find workFlow subscription ID, to start workFlow with jS Client object model. Where find this subscription ID of workflow in sharepoint 2007:

```
    BaseID="{2D9D5E35-08A5-4F55-8AB7-6821A5FE6B86}"
    DocLibID="{42E392DE-D650-4AAE-BA6E-1506A16DB8AC}"
    XomlHref="Workflows/DislikeWorkFlowCounter/DislikeWorkFlowCounter.xoml"
    XomlVersion="V3.0"
```

What is the subscription ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the subscription ID ?**

Is an association id between the workflow and list or site .

**Where find workFlow subscription ID?**

I don't have a SharePoint 2007 environment now but I think it's the same method in other SharePoint versions (I am using SharePoint 2013) :

So to get `SubscriptionId` do the following :

- Open your list that has the workflow.
- From the above ribbon > go to the `workflow settings`.
- Right click on your workflow name> select properties.

[image]

- At address  > click double click to select the full URL > copy this URL at the notepad.

[image]

- It should be like this

> http://yoursite/_layouts/15/AddWrkfl.aspx?List={BFCB62DE-07ED-44EA-9650-25EEC7490B45}&SubscriptionId={579DC7FD-E5D0-4BB6-A328-4B5A73E24F28}

- Now you can get `SubscriptionId={579DC7FD-E5D0-4BB6-A328-4B5A73E24F28}`